# scanf doesn't assign value to a second variable

Tags: c, input, scanf

I've been trying to read some input from the user in C, but it doesn't seem to work as I wish it would have. I try to read a string until the user writes a colon, and then assign the colon (':') into a different variable. It works perfectly unless the colon is the first character. In that case, it simply assigns a value of -52 to both variables and reads the colon in the next scanf. I try to make it so the colon will be assigned to the second variable, even when it's first. I've tried looking online but couldn't find any solution... Any tip will be very appriciated, thanks!

My attempt:

```
char ch, name[200];
scanf("%[^:]%c", &name, &ch);
printf("%s\n%c\n", name, ch);
```

for a valid input such as:

```
Nadav Freedman: rest_of_input
```

it works and assigns `"Nadav Freedman"` to `name` and `':'` to `ch`

but for an invalid input such as:

```
: rest_of_input
```

it simply doesn't assign any value to the variables, although I would like to save the colon to `ch`.

Comment: Don 't use `&` with a string.

Comment: `scanf()` stops as soon as it fails to process one of the formats. So if it can't process `%[^:]` it stops and doesn't assign to the remaining variables.

Comment: You will also want `scanf("%[^:]: %c"` to avoid reading the `':' ` as the character. And if `rest_of_input` is more than a single character, the `"%c"` is not what you want. You will further need `" %[^:]: %c"` because `"%[..]"` does not discard leading whtespace and you will leave `'\n'` unread in your input stream. ALL of which are reasons why you do not want to use `scanf()` for user-input. Use `fgets()/sscanf()` instead.

Comment: Always check the return value of `scanf`. That's what tells you whether the input was valid.

Comment: In this case what you probably want is `fgets()` followed by `strtok()` or `strtok_r()`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the feedback! I am less familiar with `fgets()`, would you mind sharing an example of this?

Comment: `%[` considers input to fail if it did not successfully read at least one character. Always check the return value of scanf to see how many specifiers succeeded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` stops reading as soon as any of the specifier provided doesn't match the input, so in your case if the `%[^:]` fails the function stops reading and the `%c` specifier isn't processed.

So to force it to read the colon use 2 `scanf`s instead of 1:

```
char ch, name[200];
if(scanf(" %199[^:]", name) != 1) name[0] = '\0';
scanf("%c", &ch);
printf("%s\n%c\n", name, ch);
```

OBS: I've also added the leading space to eliminate leading blank characters. And limited it to read up to 199 characters, so as not to exceed the size of the array `name`. And also changed it to update the array `name` to store an empty string if the first `scanf` fails to read anything.

Comment: Since the first `scanf` can fail, nothing is written to `name`. `name` has uninitilzied memory and in the case of a failed `scanf` should be zeroed. E.g, ```if(scanf(" %199[^:]", name) != 1) name[0] = '\0';```

Comment: @BoR yes, well noted, I've added it to the answer.

Comment: @isrnick, the same can happen to the second `scanf` too, but it depends on how picky we want to be :-)

Comment: @BoR Of course, but in Navad's examples all possible inputs have a colon, and only the name before the colon may be missing in an "invalid input", however I agree that all scanfs should be checked regardless, but I think as far as the answer to this thread goes this is enough, and I'll leave it to Nadav to expand it to treat any kind of "invalid input" possible, or not.